# how latch has no effect in javafx?

Tags: javafx, countdownlatch

I encounter a problem in developing javafx, I find `latch` has no effect in JavaFx, for example, in the following code:

```
public class JavafxLatchDemo1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        TextArea txtOut = new TextArea();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(txtOut);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        //invoke rpc function
        Callable<Integer> fibCall = new fibCallable(latch, txtOut);
        FutureTask<Integer> fibTask = new FutureTask<Integer>(fibCall);
        Thread fibThread = new Thread(fibTask);
        fibThread.start();
        latch.await(); //阻塞等待计数为0 


        txtOut.appendText("\n Say 'Hello World'");
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    } 
}
```

---

```
class fibCallable implements Callable<Integer>{        
    CountDownLatch latch;
    TextArea txtInput;

    fibCallable(CountDownLatch mylatch, TextArea txtIn){
        latch = mylatch;
        txtInput = txtIn;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        int temp1=1,temp2=0;

        System.out.println("Client will pay money for eshop");

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            temp1 = temp1 + temp2;
            temp2 = temp1;
        }
        System.out.println("Client already decide to pay money for eshop");

        Platform.runLater(()->{
            txtInput.appendText("\nWhy, am I first?");

        });
        latch.countDown(); //计数减1 

        return (new Integer(temp1));
    }  
}
```

Since I set a latch to stop JavaFx main thread in `latch.await();`, and want the callable thread `fibCallable` output the content first: so I expect:

```
Why, am I first?
 Say 'Hello World'
```

but the real output is opposite:

```
Say 'Hello World'
Why, am I first?
```

why? and a solution?

Answer (score 2):

`Platform.runLater()` submits a runnable to be executed on the FX Application Thread. The `start()` method is also executed on the FX Application Thread. So the `Runnable` you submitted with `Platform.runLater()` cannot be executed until anything already executing on that thread completes.

So you start your `fibThread` in the background and then immediately wait for the latch: this blocks the FX Application Thread. The `fibThread` does a little bit of work and then submits a call to the (blocked) FX Application Thread. Then the `fibThread` releases the latch: the currently-blocked FX Application thread unblocks and finishes the current method call (appending the text `"Say Hello World"` to the text area and displaying the stage), and at some point after that the runnable submitted to `Platform.runLater()` executes on the same thread.

A "quick and dirty" fix is simply to wrap the second call to `txtOut.appendText(...)` in another `Platform.runLater()`:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> txtOut.appendText("\n Say 'Hello World'"));
```

This is guaranteed to work, because runnables passed to `Platform.runLater()` are guaranteed to be executed in the order in which they are passed, and the countdown latch establishes a "happens-before" relationship between the two calls to `Platform.runLater()`.

Note however that you are blocking the FX Application Thread with the call to `latch.await()`, which is bad practice (and will delay the display of the stage until the background thread completes). You should really put the call to `latch.await()`, along with the second `Platform.runLater()` in another background thread. Also note that you don't really need the latch at all, as you already have a `FutureTask`, and you can just wait for its result (this will be equivalent to waiting for the latch). So you can do

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavafxLatchDemo1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException {
//        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        TextArea txtOut = new TextArea();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(txtOut);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        //invoke rpc function
//        Callable<Integer> fibCall = new fibCallable(latch, txtOut);
        Callable<Integer> fibCall = new fibCallable(txtOut);
        FutureTask<Integer> fibTask = new FutureTask<Integer>(fibCall);
        Thread fibThread = new Thread(fibTask);
        fibThread.start();
//        latch.await(); //阻塞等待计数为0 


        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                // wait for fibTask to complete:
                fibTask.get();
                // and now append text to text area,
                // but this now must be done back on the FX Application Thread
                Platform.runLater(() -> txtOut.appendText("\n Say 'Hello World'"));
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                // ignore interruption: thread is exiting anyway....
            }
        }).start();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    } 

    class fibCallable implements Callable<Integer>{        
//        CountDownLatch latch;
        TextArea txtInput;

        fibCallable(TextArea txtIn){
            txtInput = txtIn;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            int temp1=1,temp2=0;

            System.out.println("Client will pay money for eshop");

            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                temp1 = temp1 + temp2;
                temp2 = temp1;
            }

            System.out.println("Client already decide to pay money for eshop");

            Platform.runLater(()->{
                txtInput.appendText("\nWhy, am I first?");

            });
//            latch.countDown(); //计数减1 

            return (new Integer(temp1));
        }  
    }
}
```

Finally, note that JavaFX has a [concurrency API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html) of its own, that supports various callbacks on the FX Application Thread directly. This API usually means you can avoid getting your hands dirty with latches and locks, etc.

Comment: @EastJiang Mark the answer as correct if it answers the question